# How to install a specific version of granite dependency on Ubuntu 18.0.4?

Tags: 18.04, dependencies, compiling, vala

I am trying to build Akira on Ubuntu 18.0.4.2.

I checked the instruction at the Github site: https://github.com/akiraux/Akira#-compile, and installed all dependencies by using `sudo apt install`.

After I ran the instructed command: `meson build --prefix=/usr -Dprofile=default`, I saw the error output as following:

```
Dependency granite found: NO found '0.5' but need: '>= 5.2.0'
Found CMake: /usr/bin/cmake (3.10.2)
Dependency granite found: NO (tried cmake)

meson.build:17:0: ERROR: Invalid version of dependency, need 'granite' ['>= 5.2.0'] found '0.5'.
```

How do I resolve this situation to run meson successfully?

Answer (score 3):

I figured out that I need to install it from the source. Once done, granite was installed with version 5.2.3

```
# Install dependency, this was required before proceeding
sudo apt-get install libgirepository1.0-dev

# Clone the latest master
git clone git@github.com:elementary/granite.git

# Navigate to the latest cloned repo folder
cd granite

# Run meson
meson build --prefix=/usr

# Navigate to build directory
cd build

# Build using ninja
ninja && sudo ninja install
```

Answer (score 3):

Hi I'm trying to compile Akira on 18.04 as well. For me building granite from source did not work. but then I found that you can just install the `libgranite-dev`package.

Comment: I think this is the best solution. It works because the `-dev` package provides header files, which are needed for building software that uses the library. Even if the library is already installed, without the header files one cannot build software that uses it. (Installing the `-dev` package also installs the library as a dependency; specifically, [`libranite-dev` declares the `libgranite5` package as a dependency](https://packages.ubuntu.com/eoan/libgranite-dev).)